# What can I do when the owner of an answer rejects my edit that improves the readability?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

First of all, is [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13123936) acceptable and second, what can I do if it is so?

Is there even anything I can do?

Comment: Meh. You removed a little noise and improved formatting, but the post is still understandable without your edits I believe. Maybe you should just move on.

Comment: Yes, collect 76 more reputation as quick as you can :) (although in this case I'd imagine the author of the answer would just rollback, he knows what he's doing).

Comment: @Gimby Hey, fast enough? 

Comment: Faster than me! It'll probably take me another year or two to get to 3k at this rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the edit is acceptable, but it is only a small improvement to the post. The author of the post has a binding vote to approve/reject the edit (and can also rollback the changes later). I wouldn't start an edit war, by re-submitting the edit, about something minor like this. There are a lot of other posts around which *do* require editing to be useful.